# Microsoft Computer Vision API Handwriting

Tags: api, azure, computer-vision, orc

I am trying to use Microsoft's Computer Vision API service to detect handwriting and convert it to a machine readable text. However, when I test this service on their website after providing my API key, it just returns the header 202 Accepted without returning any results. If I switch the paramere handwriting to false, it returns the header 200 but the results are not readable.

Here is where I am testing their service:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56f91f2d778daf23d8ec6739/operations/587f2c6a154055056008f200/console

Just add your API key, change handwriting to true and include any picture that has handwriting.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Receiving 202 response. But no data.

Answer (score 3):

Just follow the `Operation-Location` header returned in the `202` response.

E.g.

```
$ curl https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/textOperations/2bd07b09-f7da-4028-aad1-afd239303722 \
       -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: COMPUTER_VISION_API_KEY"
```

```json
{
    "status": "Succeeded",
    "recognitionResult": {
        "lines": [
            {
                "boundingBox": [
                    0,
                    316,
                    276,
                    321,
                    275,
                    368,
                    0,
                    363
                ],
                "text": "unlikely on my terms.",
    ...
                "text": "writer My real dream is to live and work",
    ...
                "text": "to be a freelance illustrator or a freelance",
    ...
```

Input image:

[image: handwriting sample]

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/faq:

> Question: How long does the handwriting recognition operation take?
>
> Answer: The amount of time that it takes depends on the length of the text. For longer texts, it can take up to several seconds. Therefore, after the Recognize Handwritten Text operation completes, you may need to wait before you can retrieve the results using the Get Handwritten Text Operation Result operation.

Comment: This means there will be 2 API calls? One for vision api with mode parameter and another to the one you mentioned with uuid?

Comment: No idea if it counts as one or two API calls. It's important to mention here that the Computer Vision API changed significantly in 2019, having way better OCR precision. `/recognizeText` endpoint only handled handwritten text in v1, in v2 it covers both handwritten and printed text. The v2 engine is brand new, although the calling mechanics seems to have stayed the same. More in the [API documentation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc).

Answer (score 0):

This API work only if the image has 100% handwritten text. If it has a mix of printed and handwritten text, it does not differentiate between them and output both even if you set mode=Handwritten (i.e., you want only handwritten text)

Comment: The statement still holds true for v1 endpoint, however in v2 it is able to recognize both handwritten and printed text in the same API call - https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5adf991815e1060e6355ad44/operations/56f91f2e778daf14a499e1fc